# Using Java to read image from file, and saving it to a different file

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to do the above, but each time, I keep getting the following error`java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\User\Desktop\Scrap\main\out\production\resources\ProfilePic\xas.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Here's the function I used to do this

```
  private URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/ProfilePic");
  public final String PICTURE_DIRECTORY  = url.toString();


 public String createNewPicture (String path, String newPictureName) {
    int width = 12;
    int height = 12;
    BufferedImage bf = null;
    File f = null;
    String dst = PICTURE_DIRECTORY +"/"+newPictureName+".png";
    try{
        f = new File("F://a.jpg");
        bf = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        bf = ImageIO.read(f);
        System.out.println("read file successfully");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        dst = PICTURE_DIRECTORY +"/"+newPictureName+".png";
        new File (PICTURE_DIRECTORY, newPictureName+".png");
        f = new File(dst);
       ImageIO.write(bf, "png", f);
        //System.out.println("asaas " +dst);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return dst;
}
```

Can someone please help me? Spent several hours trying to solve this but stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Does the directory exists?

Comment: You don't need the line,  `bf = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` You just get rid of it on the next line. Which line is causing the file not found? Also you cannot write to a resource like that. Your PICTURE_DIRECTORY is wrong.

Comment: The directory *doesn't* exist. There are several lines of redundant code here.

Comment: `ImageIO` is great when you want to display or modify images. For copying files, it's simply the wrong solution. Use `Files.copy(...)`, see the [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you need is found in the error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\User\Desktop\Scrap\main\out\production\resources\ProfilePic\xas.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

The problem in your code is found here:

```
private URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/ProfilePic");
public final String PICTURE_DIRECTORY  = url.toString();
```

A URL contains a protocol, `"file"` in your case. The URL class' `toString()` simply returns the full URL, *including protocol*. 
You now have variable `PICTURE_DIRECTORY` containing `"file:/C:/..."`. This is not a valid path on any Windows OS.

If you really want to write to a resource (*not recommended*), you could do:

```
public final String PICTURE_DIRECTORY  = toFile(url).getAbsolutePath(); 

static private File toFile(final URL url) {
    try {
        return new File(url.toURI());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

But note that a resource, as returned by `Class..getResource(..)`, isn't always a file. It could just as well be an entry in a JAR (which you can't write to, in the same way as writing a file).

A better approach would probably be to use a directory relative to your users home directory, or other configured directory.

Finally, as I mentioned in the comments, using `ImageIO` for copying (image) files is usually the wrong solution. Instead, use `Files.copy(...)`, as in the [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) tutorial.

Comment: in addition: this would work across the platforms, since java figures out how to translate it to the os-specific location